# How to input a list of tuples

Tags: python, tuples

I am coding a python program related to graphs.
My main is like this

```
if __name__=='__main__': 
cns = [(0,1), (0,2),(1,2), (1,3),(3,1)]
G=make_graph(cns)
r=DFS(G)
```

I want to change the program such that the user can input the data.

```
cns = [(0,1), (0,2),(1,2), (1,3),(3,1)]
```

this list is to be read from the user.
How to input a list of tuples, how to do that?

Can I use `raw_input` for this purpose?

Comment: Anything that gets entered by the user using `raw_input` will be  string type. You will have to parse that data and create your list of tuples inside your program. You can have the user enter comma seperated values, which you can then take and convert into a list tuples. `0,1,0,2,1,2,1,3,3,1`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
from ast import literal_eval

cns = literal_eval(raw_input("Please enter the data: "))
```

Comment: here only one tuple can be entered..right?  do i have to append the other values to the list?

Comment: Yeah, to be clear, you can enter it exactly as you would enter it in a Python program.

Answer (score 0):

```
points = map(lambda x:map(float,x.split(",")),
         iter(lambda:raw_input("Enter X,Y coordinates or Nothing to continue").strip(),""))
print points
```

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add to kindall's answer.
When you run kindall's code, you are asked to enter the data. To enter a tuple, you can enter (1,2,3). Now to check if it's actually a tuple, you can add 2 lines: cns[0]=8
                 print cns

The output will give some error: "TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment".

Then, you know that cns is a tuple. 
Thanks @kindall!

Comment: Please do not shout if you want to mention someone please use @ follow the user name.